# Android Web Browser That Displays Forward Button

Tags: android, ios

So I am tired of having to do 2 clicks in Chrome to go forward but not backwards.

Are there any web browsers that look and work as close to Apple's safari?

Ideally I would like the navigation bar(back,home,recent apps buttons) to be hidden at the bottom similar to Android Games.

Comment: I'm confused by the last edit! You say that you want the browser to be similar to Safari, but then you don't want the bottom bar. I never used Safari, but from [screenshots](https://goo.gl/images/AtvPJR) found online it seems like it has a bottom navigation bar just like Opera mini. Can you edit your question to explain this discrepancy?

Comment: @Bochur iPhones don't have a navigation bar similar to full screen android games. I haven't installed opera mini but it appears by the pics it should work.  I will an edit clarifying in a bit hopefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Opera mini](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.mini.native) has it. It also looks a little like Safari.

(You can see the forward button on the bottom left of the screenshot)
[image]

Comment: I do not see "***it***" ... probably because your screenprint is waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaay to biiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig. Please adapt the size of your image. Tip: add an "m" right in front of the ".jpg" filename ...

Comment: aha, now we are cooking, merci!

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens sorry about that. I'm using the Android se app, and here it doesn't look as big as you're probably seeing using a browser

Comment: I really like this app except that is has 2 bars the opera and navigation bar on top of each other.  Ideally I am looking for either a combined bar or to had the default android bar.

Comment: In Settings, try the full screen mode. This will hide both when scrolling. Also this is exactly how Safari looks like ASAIK

Comment: Unfortunately not quite how safari works but still +1.  Basically safari still displays the status bar forward & back buttons.

Answer (score 1):

[CM Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ksmobile.cb&hl=en) is a very good browser that has forward and backward buttons in plain sight. I'm using it for at least 4 years and I'm really happy with it and also its security features.

Answer (score 0):

My app [Subhash Browser & Feed Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vsubhash.droid.subhashbrowser&hl=en) has a toolbar with all kinds of functions including Back and Forward history navigation. The home button is used to quit the browser but there is a Favorites button that you can use. The toolbar is at the top. You can hide it by shaking the device or using an option from the menu. I am not sure how Apple Safari is but this app is for Android.

[image: Toolbar in Subhash Browser]